# Use existing clisp stream

Tags: clisp

I am a lisp novice using clisp-2.49.

I am trying to write lisp to mimic this fairly simple piece of bash:

```
for i in $(program-1)
do
  some-logic
  program-2 $i
done | program-3
```

There are various ways of executing programs 1 and 3 (run-program, make-pipe-io-stream and probably others), all of which evaluate the form and return a stream for me to use. But for program-2, I need to run the program and tell the form to use the stream which I *already have opened*. I can find no form for this. Have I overlooked something obvious? Is there some subtlety of which I am not aware?

Many thanks, R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the undocumented function [`ext::launch`](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/src/pathname.d#l8539) and pass it `:output pipe-stream`.

Alternatively, you can pass the whole shell script as a string to [EXT:RUN-SHELL-COMMAND](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/shell.html).

However, generally speaking, Lisp is not designed to be [a replacement for shell](http://www.clisp.org/clash.html). You would probably be better off by juggling your `program-*` execution in shell.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `launch`. I will take a closer look.  
  
I was not so much _treating lisp as a shell_, more that I am learning the language, I needed a simple project and converting the existing shell script seemed like a good idea.  
  
I had inferred from the lisp advocacy that lisp is a flexible, versatile language which is well suited for tricky problems - so I assumed that when I struggled with a simple problem that the fault must be with my reasoning.  
  
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  
  
Would it be fair to assume then that clisp has little or no programmer access to low-level process manipulation (fork/exec etc). Which is presumably what bash is using in this situation?

Comment: You are welcome. Clisp has full access to [glibc via ffi](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/bindings/glibc/linux.lisp); see also [syscalls](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/syscalls.html); see also the `clash` link in my answer.